# How to pass in some values to the state and feetch the data to monogodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm a beginner in dealing with connecting back-end, front-end and mongodb all together so im sorry if my question isnt asked in the right place.

I was trying to let the user input some data in a text box and save the data in a value property but for some reaon its not being saved inside the databody => message variable which i really dont know why. What im trying to do is call the function that sends the data in a button tag and by the time its called the data the user inputed would be sent to the server.

The values of databody and value are [object object] and undefined respectively

Here is my ping.js file. Hope the code would make more sense!

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { brand: "Ford" };
  }
handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("its running");
    let databody = {
      message: this.state.val,
    };
    console.log(" the message is :" + databody);
    console.log(" the message is :" + this.val);
    return fetch("http://localhost:5000/stored", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(databody),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ok2">
        <textarea
          className="message"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Write me somthing!. Also, double click to ping:) "
          value={this.state.val}
        ></textarea>
        <body>
          <button
            className="button"
            onClick={() => {
              this.magic();
              this.handleSubmit(); //animation + //pinging the phone
              // this.handleButtonClick(); //setVal(() => ""); //sets the value of the box to empty
            }}
          >
</button>
```

This is my index.js file in the back-end Node js

```
app.post("/stored", (req, res) => {
  console.log("its running 2: " + req.body);
  db.collection("quotes").insertOne(req.body, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.send("saved to db: " + data);
  });
});
```

These are the errors im getting because of this problem:
[image]

*im using react.js, node.js and mongodb in vs code*

Comment: For one error: You need to add cors at your backend. If you are using express - Import/require cors and use it as app.use(cors()). For issue with logging, you use this.state.val and this.val… is val defined anywhere?

Comment: no val is just defined in the handleSubmit function. Am I supposed to define it somwhere else? and how exactly?

Comment: @StefanZivkovic what do you think?

Comment: `this.val`/`this.state.val` is not defined anywhere, thats why in the console.log there is `undefined`. Also if you try `JSON.stringify(databody)` maybe something like `{message: undefined}` will be printed instead of `[object: Object]`. I see you have `brand` in your state, why don't you try to use that and then see what happens? Because brand exists and it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of cors (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) which just makes sure no one can make requests to an api unless he is permitted. In your backend which I believe is express you need to install cors  with `npm i cors` and add these two lines of code in the file where your creating the server i.e index.js, app.js

```js
const cors = require("cors"); // Importing cors
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" })); // Use cors before every req
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your screenshot and i found cors error in screenshot.
First, you fix the cors error.
You can guide to fix cors error.

1. If you are using express server.

https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/

2. If you are using normal http or https server

https://bigcodenerd.org/enable-cors-node-js-without-express/

and then second.
Currently, I can't understand this code.

```
    return (
      <div className="ok2">
        <textarea
          className="message"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Write me somthing!. Also, double click to ping:) "
          value={this.state.val}
        ></textarea>
        <body>
          <button
            className="button"
            onClick={() => {
              this.magic();
              this.handleSubmit(); //animation + //pinging the phone
              // this.handleButtonClick(); //setVal(() => ""); //sets the value of the box to empty
            }}
          >
</button>
```

Why it need body tag and it works in parent body?

For html syntax, please guide this.

https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/html5-page-structure.html

I wish my answer help you. If you have any help, you can "add a commit"